# C# Применение AddScope ,AddTransient ,AddSingleton

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте господа программисты. Можете кто-нибудь из вас, более подробно ответит в каких проектах, приложениях применяется тот или иной тип жизненного цикла(AddScope ,AddTransient ,AddSingleton).Перерыв кучу статей , не нашел толкового объяснения , где лучше их применять. Все статьи копипастят друг друга и делают акцент на работе и отличиях, но никто не описывает области применения. Я новичок, так что судите строго. Спасибо.

Comment: Увы, невозможно дать объективный ответ на ваш вопрос. Вы читаете статьи "как устроено", из них очень хорошо понять, как устроен тот или иной инструмент, но новичкам этот подход от общего к частному непонятен. Возьмите какой-нибудь реальный проект, конкретный кейс и попробуйте задать конкретный вопрос от частного к общему -- только так вы и наработаете понимание. А так у вас ни списка статей, ни конкретного образца кода -- это только бла-бла поговорить и вы всё равно ничего опять не поймёте.

Comment: [Service lifetimes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes)

Comment: Они применяются в любых проектах и приложениях. Суть именно в продолжительности жизненного цикла. Если ресурс может существовать постоянно - делаем его Singleton. Если нужен новый экземпляр при каждом обращении к нему - делаем Transient.

Comment: О, кстати о документации и извечных демонстрациях на примере веб-запросов. Задал [вопрос в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58677289#58677289) по поводу других примеров, не только про веб. Если кому интересно -- ответьте в чатик.